# Different types for Typescript index signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've the following `interface`.

```
interface IDetails {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface IConfig {
  appName: string;
  userDetails: IDetails;
  [key: string]: string | IDetails
}

const details: IConfig = {
  appName: 'test',
  userDetails: {
    name: 'xyz',
    age: 67,
  },
}

const t: string = 'userDetails'
const name: string = details[t].name
//                              ^^^^ 
// throws the following error
//
// Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string | IDetails'.
//  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

When I try to assign multiple types/interfaces to the key signature, I get this error. I know I can use `[key: string]: any`. But, I don't want to generalize it. Is there any possible way to make this work?

[Link to TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IDetails%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IConfig%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20appName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20userDetails%3A%20IDetails%3B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20IDetails%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20details%3A%20IConfig%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20appName%3A%20'test'%2C%0D%0A%20%20userDetails%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'xyz'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%2067%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20t%3A%20string%20%3D%20'userDetails'%0D%0Aconst%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20details%5Bt%5D.name%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%5E%5E%5E%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20thorows%20an%20error%0D%0A%2F%2F%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Property%20'name'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'string%20%7C%20IDetails'.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20Property%20'name'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'string'.)

Comment: Can you cast to an IDetails: `(<IDetails>details[t]).name`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Why `string | IDetails` is not working?

Comment: Why do you have `[key: string]: string | IDetails`? without it what you're trying would just work. Are you expecting more properties?

Comment: @NitzanTomer This is a simple use case. The `t` is the example will be dynamic. So, if I need to access the properties, I need to do this.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to dynamically access the properties of `details`, then you better use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isDetails(obj: string | IDetails): obj is IDetails {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 2 && typeof obj["name"] === "string" && typeof obj["age"] === "number";
}
```

Then you can do:

```
if (isDetails(details[t])) {
    // details[t].name should be fine with the compiler
}
```